# EGit - Switching branches doesn't remove empty directories/packages

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I'm using EGIT to manage my GIT repository, which seems to work well so far.  However, when I switch from one branch to another the files are correctly switched, however empty directories and packages that exist in one branch but not the other are left over.

I understand that GIT is based on the actual files and not the directories, however this is not ideal as my one branch was a large refactoring and therefore contains many packages that the master branch does not have.

From my research there appears to be a GIT command **git clean -d** that should cleanup the directories.  Does EGIT support this?  Or is there a way to execute this command when switching the branch with EGIT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like **[bug 345585](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=345585)**: "EGit does not prune empty folders when switching branches".

It is still opened, so for now, the `git clean -d` is your best option (but outside of Eclipse, in a shell session).

---

Update June 2013, for [Egit 3.0 Kepler](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2013/06/11/egit-3-0-top-eclipse-kepler-feature-9/):

A clean action has been added to the repositories view now.

[image: clean egit action]

Comment: How though do I execute that command from EGIT?  Or do I need to connect to the GIT repository via GIT Bash?  I'm a GIT noob.

Comment: @David: you would open a bash session, go to the root directory of your project currently shared with Git (the one directory with the `.git` in it), and run the `git clean -d`.

Comment: Sorry, re-read your post, need to do it with the shell.  Thanks.

Comment: @David: beware of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267180/can-i-undo-a-git-clean-fdx or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681474/git-clean-fdx-recovery-possible: use `-n` for a dry run, as mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5879932/git-clean-not-working-recursively

Comment: Thanks for the followup... -n just saved my day